# Word for the act of accepting something only because it is the unquestioned, traditional standard

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word for when someone accepts something into their way of life, not because of any personal agreement with or liking of the idea, but solely because it is what is conventionally accepted and welcomed as societal normality.

For example,

- *Samuel never felt distinctly masculine throughout his upbringing, but since his town was very conservative to traditional gender roles, he took on a more masculine appearance throughout his life, and without thought to question, he ____.* / *, he showed* ____.

Comment: Are you looking for a word that describes an unquestioned tradition or the act of accepting it? Your example calls for the former, but your title asks for the latter.

Comment: The act of accepting it, I apologize if any confusion was brought up by the title. I will be sure to make it more proper and suitable to the question. Thank you, And happy New Year’s Eve!

Answer (score 1):

***Status quo*** would work here:

*Samuel never felt distinctly masculine throughout his upbringing, but since his town was very conservative to traditional gender roles, he took on a more masculine appearance throughout his life, and without thought to question, accepted the **status quo**.*

> **status quo**
>  (usually **the status quo**)
>      The existing state of affairs, especially
> regarding social or political issues.
>     *‘they have a vested interest in maintaining
> the status quo’*
>  <sub>Source: [Lexico: status
> quo](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/status_quo)</sub>

**Update**

Since your fill-in-the-blank has been edited from *he accepted ______* to *he ______*, it seems you are looking for a "package deal"—an intransitive verb that means "accept something for the sake of convention" rather the verb *accept* + a direct object that signifies that convention. So:

**Conformed** would work here:

*Samuel never felt distinctly masculine throughout his upbringing, but since his town was very conservative to traditional gender roles, he took on a more masculine appearance throughout his life, and without thought to question, he **conformed**.*

> **conform**
>  1 Comply with rules, standards, or laws.
> *‘the kitchen does not conform to hygiene regulations’*
>      1.1 (of a person) behave according to socially
> acceptable conventions or standards.
> *‘the pressure to conform’*
>      1.2 Be similar in form or type; agree.
> *‘the countryside should conform to a certain idea of the picturesque’*
>  <sub>Source: [Lexico:
> conform](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/conform)</sub>

Merriam-Webster notes:

> *Conform*, with its prefix *con-*, "with" or "together", means basically "to adopt the form of those around you". Thus, employee
> behavior must usually conform with basic company policies. A certain
> philosophy may be said to conform with American values (even if we
> sometimes have a hard time agreeing on exactly what those are). And a
> Maine Coon cat or a Dandie Dinmont terrier must conform to its breed
> requirements in order to be registered for breeding purposes. Being a
> conformist is usually a safe bet; being a nonconformist, who ignores
> society's standards and the whole idea of conformity, can be a bit
> dangerous but also sometimes more fun.
>  <sub>Source:
> [Merriam-Webster:
> conform](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conform)</sub>

In that passage, you can also find noun forms to work with (*was **a conformist***, *showed **conformity***).

Here's the whole thing again, cleaned up a little:

*Samuel never felt distinctly masculine during his upbringing, but since his conservative town expected traditional gender roles, he took on a masculine appearance throughout his life, and without questioning, he conformed [to its expectations].*

Comment: Grand Torini had already asked for (and received) clarification. 'Status quo' would _not_ work here (I've corrected OP's example to correspond to his expressed intention); it does not mean 'meekly accepting the status quo'.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but I believe in this context the word to use would simply be "Tradition".

*"Samuel never felt distinctly masculine throughout his upbringing, but since his town was very conservative to traditional gender roles, he took on a more masculine appearance throughout his life, and without thought to question, accepted **tradition**"*

Answer (score 0):

How about you use the Latin phrase **nolens volens**?

Here is M-W defining the phrase—

> unwilling (or) willing : like it or not

So you could say—

> "Samuel never felt distinctly masculine throughout his upbringing, but since his town was very conservative toward traditional gender roles, he took on a more masculine appearance throughout his life, and without thought to question, accepted it **nolens volens.**

Comment: I find this one lovely, although unfortunately I don’t think it is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: @Tom O' Bedlam _shibboleth_ then, maybe?

Comment: @TomO'Bedlam It's just the Latin for English *will he or nill he*.

Answer (score 0):

[**Caving to Received Wisdom**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/example/english/received-wisdom).

Cambridge offers the following example:

> ... to question the received wisdom of more conventional research.

In religion, received wisdom is its *orthodoxy*.

When a society takes an established convention as its traditional standard, it reverse-engineers the norm as wisdom, the only norm—unquestioned, as handed down from the gods, and thus immutable. Exceptions cause shock.

One person's received wisdom is another's received prejudice.

From Cambridge English Corpus:

> We should always be sceptical of received wisdom, or in its rather more dangerous guise common sense, which is often **little more than 'naturalised' ideology**.

Comment: But OP requires a verb for 'meekly accept the status quo' (or a noun for such acceptance).

Comment: It was spelled out 12 hours ago. I've put it in bold print.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: How could a noun go after *he*, such as your edit has set up the sentence?

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat Why not just re-edit to more exactly fit OP's 'word for the act of accepting ...'?

Answer (score 0):

The noun **compliance** has, as one of its (common) senses, 'meekly accept the status quo':

> *compliance* [noun] [non-count] [formal]
>
> ...
>
> (2) [mainly disapproving]
>
> the state of being too willing to do what other people want you to do:
>
> - *It's his compliance that amazes me.*

[[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/compliance)] (reformatted)

The verb is 'comply', and the idiom *toe the line* has much the same meaning (probably emphasising the regulatory pressure involved more):

*accept the authority, principles, or policies of a particular group, especially under pressure* [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/toe_the_line)]

*Follow the crowd* overlaps in meaning too, though usually there's less of a sense of dire consequences for non-compliance here.